# Copy Value From Cell in Column A to Column B And Vice Versa

Tags: forms, tables, copy-paste, value

I don't know how to exactly describe the Problem with words.
I hope it is self-explanatory what the UI does.
I can think of two variants of the Copy-Arrows.

I am looking for User-Studies or at least heuristics on which variant might be easier to understand.
I'd also be happy to know some key-words I might use to find results online.

**Variant A: Arrows Point to the middle**
[image]

**Variant B: Arrows Point to the outside**
[image]

Comment: So are the values you copy from say column A, replacing a specific cell (1B), or can they be applied elsewhere? And, are there only 2 columns, not a possibility of column C, D, etc.? Can you be more specific about the use case and constraints? Is this a common operation, or a sparsely used configuration?

Comment: Good Questions @MikeM! For Question 1: No. 1A only goes to 1B and the other way around.

Comment: For Question 2: Advanced users actually might have a third column. Fortunately it only makes sense to copy from/to the middle column. There is no need to provide a function to copy from A to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try to simplify the grouping to as few elements as possible, and put the functionality alongside the value you're going to copy.

I was looking for some strict research and studies on this, but haven't seen anything. However, you can learn on your own: test with your users.

**Reduce the visual elements users have to make sense of.**

You can take advantage of the [Gestalt principles of grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping#:%7E:text=The%20Gestalt%20law%20of%20proximity,%22assembled%22%20in%20a%20composition.) here.

> The Gestalt law of proximity states that "objects or shapes that are close to one another appear to form groups". Even if the shapes, sizes, and objects are radically different, they will appear as a group if they are close.

In either of your options, you have 4 visual distinct elements (two values, two arrows) per each row. This means that you're leaving it to the viewer to fill in the missing space, and tie the arrows to where they go and which element they belong to.

You can group each value with its only possible action. It also can help to provide:

- Instructional text
- Undo
- Hover tips if they mouse over the arrow ('copy to {{ column name }} )
- Visual feedback when the value replaces in the adjacent cell (a flash highlight, small notification that fades out, etc.)

[image]

Since you said for advanced uses, you would not copy from A to C (or vice versa), so the arrow buttons can align with where they can copy to at either end of the column.

Comment: Of course testing would be the best thing to do. Any suggestions on which questions to ask? I'd simply print both variants (with actual column- and value-names) and start asking people. I'd ask something like "How would you copy Value 1 in column A to column B?". On the other hand I could ask "what do these buttons do". Anyway: If people fail to answer 2 after saying "I'd type the value" I know the concept needs some real improvement.

Comment: I think I will play with the proximity of the arrows to the cell. Especially in the advanced case, the arrows in column B might as well manipulate the value IN the cell.

Comment: @htho in terms of testing; watch what they do, not what they say. If possible, give them a task, such as matching x number of values from column a to b, or  vice verse. They may overlook the arrows completely, and just  enter in text (if those are inputs). That's  not a  bad thing, it just means they may just be used to another way to edit. Either way you'll learn.

Comment: Although I know it is possible to let people *do* stuff with a paper prototype - I prefer a cognitive walkthrough approach. On the other hand - Wizard of Oz type of tests/prototypes are easier than ever with lo-fi prototypes (PowerPoint, Visio, ...) and screen sharing. The user clicks and the Wizard manipulates. I'll definitely try that.

Answer (score 1):

A similar situation exists in the Indesing table of contents creation window.
In this case the arrows are reduced to only two options: **add** or **remove** after selecting the item (or cell) from the left or right:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am aware of this pattern. For lists, where Items are moved from one set to another, this is a good approach. But in my case it is about copying values. The set of items is always the same in both columns. I thought about stacking the buttons like in your example, but since this is a list, the buttons would be so small (in height) they'd be hard to click/tap.